# Powerpoint change sound effect volume in macro

Tags: vba, powerpoint

is there a way that i can change the volume of a sound effect object through vba/a macro in powerpoint? even mute and unmute would be sufficient for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems, unfortunately changes on the MediaFormat properties on the active slide won't take effect immediately.
Actually I figured out some more or less complicated workarounds for these simple problems, if you just want to dynamically mute/unmute an audio associated with a shape via VBA, this will help :

```
Private start As Double

Sub toggleMuteUnmute()

  Dim sld As Slide
  Dim sha As Shape
  Dim plr As Player
  Dim newPosition As Double

  Set sld = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide
  Set sha = sld.Shapes(1)
  Set plr = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Player(sha.Id)
  
  If plr.State = ppPlaying Then ' Muting
    plr.Pause
    start = Timer()
  Else ' Unmuting with position correction
    newPosition = plr.CurrentPosition + (Timer() - start) * 1000
    If sha.MediaFormat.EndPoint > newPosition Then
      plr.CurrentPosition = newPosition
      plr.Play
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice!  A keeper.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim oSh As Shape
Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

With oSh.MediaFormat
    .Volume = 1     ' scale is 0 to 1
    .Muted = False  ' | True
End With
```

Comment: This works properly in that it will adjust the volume and mute a sound. but, for some reason, this is only working the first time the change is made when viewing the presentation. If I mute and then try to unmute it is staying muted.

Comment: Hm. You're having better luck than I am.  During a slide show, it doesn't respond at all; it only sets what happens after I quit and restart the show.  I'm not sure how to get around this one unless it's some crazy complex way of keeping track of the time the audio starts and when the mute button is clicked, then relaunching the show at that same slide after changing the start/end points of the audio so it restarts wherever it left off.  Ugly.

Comment: well, I'll tell you what I am doing. I have a board for a family feud game. For each round, I programatically grab the answers from a table at the end of the presentation, cover the opening animations for each answer box that isnt used, and (want to) mute the sound I have when each of the numbers are revealed. Then, I hit a button that does the entrance animation and sound for all 8 answers with the unused ones being hidden/muted. So, when I mute the unneeded ones, they seem to be muted, but I cannot unmute them. I dont need to mute in the middle of a clip (luckily)

Comment: I guess the least ugly workaround might be to replace the source of the sound effect with a silent track for the ones I am trying to mute?

Comment: That would make good sense.  You might need to do a View.GoToSlide after running the code for this to ensure that the slide refreshes with the new sound.

Answer (score 0):

a very ugly workaround. I am sure there is a better way of doing this, but here it is

```
Sub mute()
Dim gameSlide As Slide
Set gameSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides("Round Board")
gameSlide.Shapes("numSound 5").MediaFormat.StartPoint = gameSlide.Shapes("numSound 5").MediaFormat.Length - 1
End Sub

Sub unmute()
Dim gameSlide As Slide
Set gameSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides("Round Board")
gameSlide.Shapes("numSound 5").MediaFormat.StartPoint = 0
gameSlide.Shapes("numSound 5").MediaFormat.EndPoint = gameSlide.Shapes("numSound 5").MediaFormat.Length
End Sub
```